# Change 'sort by' in plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to edit the Gigpress code so that when events are not 'grouped by artist', they are still ordered by event date rather than artist name.

The Gigpress sidebar does this no problem so I figure that the main plugin should be able to be configured to do this somehow. Just can't get my head around this.

The plugin code is

```
<?php

// These two functions are for backwards-compatibility the shortcodes used in GigPress < 2.0
function gigpress_upcoming($filter = null, $content = null) {
if(!is_array($filter)) $filter = array();
$filter['scope'] = 'upcoming';
return gigpress_shows($filter, $content);
}
function gigpress_archive($filter = null, $content = null) {
if(!is_array($filter)) $filter = array();
$filter['scope'] = 'past';
return gigpress_shows($filter, $content);
}


function gigpress_shows($filter = null, $content = null) {

global $wpdb, $gpo;
$further_where = $limit = '';

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'tour' => FALSE,
        'artist' => FALSE,
        'venue' => FALSE,
        'limit' => FALSE,
        'scope' => 'upcoming',
        'sort' => FALSE,
        'group_artists' => 'yes',
        'artist_order' => 'custom',
        'show_menu' => FALSE,
        'show_menu_count' => FALSE,
        'menu_sort' => FALSE,
        'menu_title' => FALSE,
        'year' => FALSE,
        'month' => FALSE
    ), $filter)
);

$total_artists = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(*) from " . GIGPRESS_ARTISTS);

// Date conditionals and sorting based on scope
switch($scope) {
    case 'upcoming':
        $date_condition = "show_expire >= '" . GIGPRESS_NOW . "'";
        if(empty($sort)) $sort = 'asc';
        break;
    case 'past':
        $date_condition = "show_expire < '" . GIGPRESS_NOW . "'";
        if(empty($sort)) $sort = 'desc';
        break;
    case 'today':
        $date_condition = "show_expire >= '".GIGPRESS_NOW."' AND show_date <= '".GIGPRESS_NOW."'";
        if(empty($sort)) $sort = 'asc';
        break;
    case 'all':
        $date_condition = "show_expire != ''";
        if(empty($sort)) $sort = 'desc';
        break;
}

// Artist, tour and venue filtering
if($artist) $further_where .= ' AND show_artist_id = ' . $wpdb->prepare('%d', $artist);
if($tour) $further_where .= ' AND show_tour_id = ' . $wpdb->prepare('%d', $tour);
if($venue) $further_where .= ' AND show_venue_id = ' . $wpdb->prepare('%d', $venue);

// Date filtering

// Query vars take precedence over function vars
if(isset($_REQUEST['gpy'])) { 
    $year = $_REQUEST['gpy'];

    if(isset($_REQUEST['gpm'])) {
        $month = $_REQUEST['gpm'];
    } else {
        unset($month);
    }
    $no_limit = TRUE;
}


// Validate year and date parameters
if($year || $month) {

    if($year) {
        if(is_numeric($year) && strlen($year) == 4) {
            $year = round($year);
        } else {
            $year = date('Y', current_time('timestamp'));
        }
    } else {
        // We've only specified a month, so we'll assume the year is current
        $year = date('Y', current_time('timestamp'));
    }

    if($month) {
        if($month == 'current') {
            $month = date('m', current_time('timestamp'));
        } elseif(round($month) == 0) {
            // Probably using a month name
            $month = date('m', strtotime($month));
        } elseif(round($month) < 10) {
            // Make sure the month is padded through 09
            $month = str_pad($month, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
        } elseif(round($month) < 13) {
            // Between 10 and 12 we're OK
            $month = $month;
        } else {
            // Bogus month value (not a string and > 12)
            // Sorry, bailing out. Your "month" will be ignored. Dink.
            $month = FALSE;
        }
        $start_month = $end_month = $month;
    }

    if(!$month) {
        $start_month = '01';
        $end_month = '12';
    }

    $start = $year.'-'.$start_month.'-01';
    $end = $year.'-'.$end_month.'-31';
    $further_where .= ' AND show_date BETWEEN '.$wpdb->prepare('%s', $start).' AND '.$wpdb->prepare('%s', $end);
}


$limit = ($limit && !$no_limit) ? ' LIMIT ' . $wpdb->prepare('%d', $limit) : '';
$artist_order = ($artist_order == 'custom') ?  "artist_order ASC," : '';

// With the new 'all' scope, we should probably have a third message option, but I'm too lazy
// Really, there should just be one generic 'no shows' message. Oh well.
$no_results_message = ($scope == 'upcoming') ? wptexturize($gpo['noupcoming']) : wptexturize($gpo['nopast']);

ob_start();

// Are we showing our menu?
if($show_menu) {
    $menu_options = array();
    $menu_options['scope'] = $scope;
    $menu_options['type'] = $show_menu;
    if($menu_title) $menu_options['title'] = $menu_title;
    if($show_menu_count) $menu_options['show_count'] = $show_menu_count;
    if($menu_sort) $menu_options['sort'] = $menu_sort;
    if($artist) $menu_options['artist'] = $artist;
    if($tour) $menu_options['tour'] = $tour;
    if($venue) $menu_options['venue'] = $venue;

    include gigpress_template('before-menu');
    echo gigpress_menu($menu_options);
    include gigpress_template('after-menu');
}

// If we're grouping by artist, we'll unfortunately have to first get all artists
// Then  make a query for each one. Looking for a better way to do this.

if($group_artists == 'yes' && !$artist && $total_artists > 1) { 

    $artists = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . GIGPRESS_ARTISTS . " ORDER BY " . $artist_order . "artist_name ASC");

    foreach($artists as $artist_group) {
        $shows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . GIGPRESS_ARTISTS . " AS a, " . GIGPRESS_VENUES . " as v, " . GIGPRESS_SHOWS ." AS s LEFT JOIN  " . GIGPRESS_TOURS . " AS t ON s.show_tour_id = t.tour_id WHERE " . $date_condition . " AND show_status != 'deleted' AND s.show_artist_id = " . $artist_group->artist_id . " AND s.show_artist_id = a.artist_id AND s.show_venue_id = v.venue_id " . $further_where . " ORDER BY s.show_date " . $sort . ",s.show_expire " . $sort . ",s.show_time ". $sort . $limit);

        if($shows) {
            // For each artist group

            $some_results = TRUE;
            $current_tour = '';
            $i = 0;
            $showdata = array(
                'artist' => wptexturize($artist_group->artist_name),
                'artist_id' => $artist_group->artist_id
            );

            include gigpress_template('shows-artist-heading');
            include gigpress_template('shows-list-start');

            foreach($shows as $show) {

                // For each individual show

                $showdata = gigpress_prepare($show, 'public');

                if($showdata['tour'] && $showdata['tour'] != $current_tour && !$tour) {
                    $current_tour = $showdata['tour'];
                    include gigpress_template('shows-tour-heading');
                }

                $class = $showdata['status'];
                ++ $i; $class .= ($i % 2) ? '' : ' gigpress-alt';
                if(!$showdata['tour'] && $current_tour) {
                    $current_tour = '';
                    $class .= ' divider';
                }
                $class .= ($showdata['tour'] && !$tour) ? ' gigpress-tour' : '';

                include gigpress_template('shows-list');

            }

            include gigpress_template('shows-list-end');                        
        }
    }

    if($some_results) {
    // After all artist groups
        include gigpress_template('shows-list-footer');
    } else {    
        // No shows from any artist
        include gigpress_template('shows-list-empty');
    }

} else {

    // Not grouping by artists

    $shows = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT * FROM " . GIGPRESS_ARTISTS . " AS a, " . GIGPRESS_VENUES . " as v, " . GIGPRESS_SHOWS ." AS s LEFT JOIN  " . GIGPRESS_TOURS . " AS t ON s.show_tour_id = t.tour_id WHERE " . $date_condition . " AND show_status != 'deleted' AND s.show_artist_id = a.artist_id AND s.show_venue_id = v.venue_id " . $further_where . " ORDER BY s.show_date " . $sort . ",s.show_expire " . $sort . ",s.show_time " . $sort . $limit);

    if($shows) {

        $current_tour = '';
        $i = 0;

        include gigpress_template('shows-list-start');

        foreach($shows as $show) {

            // For each individual show
            $showdata = gigpress_prepare($show, 'public');

            if($showdata['tour'] && $showdata['tour'] != $current_tour && !$tour) {
                $current_tour = $showdata['tour'];
                include gigpress_template('shows-tour-heading');
            }

            $class = $showdata['status'];
            ++ $i; $class .= ($i % 2) ? '' : ' gigpress-alt';
            if(!$showdata['tour'] && $current_tour) {
                $current_tour = '';
                $class .= ' divider';
            }
            $class .= ($showdata['tour'] && !$tour) ? ' gigpress-tour' : '';

            include gigpress_template('shows-list');
        }

        include gigpress_template('shows-list-end');
        include gigpress_template('shows-list-footer');         

    } else {
        // No shows to display
        include gigpress_template('shows-list-empty');
    }   

}

echo('<!-- Generated by GigPress ' . GIGPRESS_VERSION . ' -->
');
return ob_get_clean();  
}


function gigpress_menu($options = null) {

global $wpdb, $wp_locale, $gpo; 

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'type' => 'monthly',
    'base' => get_permalink(),
    'scope' => 'upcoming',
    'title' => FALSE,
    'id' => 'gigpress_menu',
    'show_count' => FALSE,
    'artist' => FALSE,
    'tour' => FALSE,
    'venue' => FALSE,
    'sort' => 'desc'
), $options));

$base .= (strpos($base, '?') === FALSE) ? '?' : '&amp;';

// Date conditionals based on scope
switch($scope) {
    case 'upcoming':
        $date_condition = ">= '" . GIGPRESS_NOW . "'";
        break;
    case 'past':
        $date_condition = "< '" . GIGPRESS_NOW . "'";
        break;
    case 'all':
        $date_condition = "!= ''";
}

$further_where = '';

// Artist, tour and venue filtering
if($artist) $further_where .= ' AND show_artist_id = ' . $wpdb->prepare('%d', $artist);
if($tour) $further_where .= ' AND show_tour_id = ' . $wpdb->prepare('%d', $tour);
if($venue) $further_where .= ' AND show_venue_id = ' . $wpdb->prepare('%d', $venue);    

// Variable operajigamarations based on monthly vs. yearly
switch($type) {
    case 'monthly':
        $sql_select_extra = 'MONTH(show_date) AS month, ';
        $sql_group_extra = ', MONTH(show_date)';
        $title = ($title) ? wptexturize(strip_tags($title)) : __('Select Month');
        $current = (isset($_REQUEST['gpy']) && isset($_REQUEST['gpm'])) ? $_REQUEST['gpy'].$_REQUEST['gpm'] : '';
        break;
    case 'yearly':
        $sql_select_extra = $sql_group_extra = '';
        $title = ($title) ? wptexturize(strip_tags($title)) : __('Select Year');
        $current = (isset($_REQUEST['gpy'])) ? $_REQUEST['gpy'] : '';
}

// Build query
$dates = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT YEAR(show_date) AS year, " . $sql_select_extra . " count(show_id) as shows 
    FROM ".GIGPRESS_SHOWS." 
    WHERE show_status != 'deleted' 
    AND show_date " . $date_condition . $further_where . " 
    GROUP BY YEAR(show_date)" . $sql_group_extra . " 
    ORDER BY show_date " . $sort);

ob_start();

if($dates) : ?>

        <select name="gigpress_menu" class="gigpress_menu" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <option value="<?php echo $base; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></option>
        <?php foreach($dates as $date) : ?>
            <?php $this_date = ($type == 'monthly') ? $date->year.$date->month : $date->year; ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $base.'gpy='.$date->year; if($type == 'monthly') echo '&amp;gpm='.$date->month; ?>"<?php if($this_date == $current) : ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                <?php if($type == 'monthly') echo $wp_locale->get_month($date->month).' '; echo $date->year; ?> 
                <?php if($show_count && $show_count == 'yes') : ?>(<?php echo $date->shows; ?>)<?php endif; ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>

<?php endif;

return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: What is your concrete question? Into which concrete problem did you run while rewriting the plugin? Can you tell specifically what stops you from rewriting it?

Comment: @hakre I don't know how to rewrite so the 'not grouping by artists' option orders events by date instead of by artist name. I didn't write the plugin from scratch. The plugin is Gigpress.

Comment: @Kelvin did I solve your question? If yes please accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The line under `// Not grouping by artists`

Change from:

```
$shows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . GIGPRESS_ARTISTS . " AS a, " . GIGPRESS_VENUES . " as v, " . GIGPRESS_SHOWS ." AS s LEFT JOIN  " . GIGPRESS_TOURS . " AS t ON s.show_tour_id = t.tour_id WHERE " . $date_condition . " AND show_status != 'deleted' AND s.show_artist_id = a.artist_id AND s.show_venue_id = v.venue_id " . $further_where . " ORDER BY s.show_date " . $sort . ",s.show_expire " . $sort . ",s.show_time " . $sort . $limit);
```

To:

```
$shows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . GIGPRESS_ARTISTS . " AS a, " . GIGPRESS_VENUES . " as v, " . GIGPRESS_SHOWS ." AS s LEFT JOIN  " . GIGPRESS_TOURS . " AS t ON s.show_tour_id = t.tour_id WHERE " . $date_condition . " AND show_status != 'deleted' AND s.show_artist_id = a.artist_id AND s.show_venue_id = v.venue_id " . $further_where . " ORDER BY a.artist_name ASC,s.show_date " . $sort . ",s.show_expire " . $sort . ",s.show_time " . $sort . $limit);
```